# AttributeError when trying to created nested serializer in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models of sets, and cards. Theses models have one to many relationship where there are many cards in a single set. These model are join by a foreign key -  each card has `set_id` which is equal to the `id` of the set. These IDs are `UUID`.

I am trying to create a serializer using Django REST Framework where I return the details of the set, as well as including all the cards that are part of the set.

**error**

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `cards` on serializer `SetSerializers`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Set` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Set' object has no attribute 'cards'.
```

**serializers.py**

```py
class CardSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Card
        fields = ['id', 'number', 'name', 'set_id']

class SetSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cards = CardSerializers()

    class Meta:
        model = Set
        fields = ['id', 'code', 'name', 'releaseDate','cards']
```

**models.py**

```py
class Set(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    ...

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Card(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    ...
    set = models.ForeignKey(Set, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Cards', related_query_name='Cards')


    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```py
class SetsIndividualData(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = SetSerializers

    def get_queryset(self):
        setCode = self.kwargs.get('setCode')
        queryList = Set.objects.filter(code=setCode.upper())
        return queryList
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in your code.

`models.py`:

In the `Card` model, the `related_name` of the FK should be lowercase as per below:

```
set = models.ForeignKey(Set, related_name="cards", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`serializers.py`:

In your `SetSerializers` you had the right idea, but you need to be more specific with your `CardSerializers`, as you are describing a "to-many" relationship.

Please refer to the docs here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

Moreover, from your `views.py` I can see you will only send `GET` requests, therefore you can have your cards to be read only.
So the serializer `card` attribute would look like the below:

```
cards = CardSerializers(many=True, read_only=True)
```

`views.py`:

It looks like you want to retrieve a set by id.
`ListAPIView` is the wrong generics, you should use `RetrieveAPIView` instead, as it provides a `get` method and is used to retrieve a single model instance.

Please refer to the docs for more information: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveapiview